# bootstrap theme not working in ASP.Net MVC 5 project

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, bootswatch

I have downloaded bootstrap theme named flatly from bootswatch.com. I have set it up using instructions from [How can I implement a theme from bootswatch or wrapbootstrap in an MVC 5 project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839351/how-can-i-implement-a-theme-from-bootswatch-or-wrapbootstrap-in-an-mvc-5-project).
But my bootstrap theme still not working. It gives me lots of warnings. I have copied downloaded flatly.bootstrap.css theme to Content directory and modified Bundleconfig.cs file, i have added new bundle: bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/flatly.bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css")); but that theme not working correctly: here is my screenshot of my website [website image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8YZ9.png)
Who can help me with this issue? Also watch image attached:[Warnings image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ke1f.png)

Comment: Clarify your problem, there is no useful information that can help to us help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your 'navbar' code code in _Layout.cshtml. You might be already using the below code -

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Replace it with below one from getbootstrap.com. But before that ensure that you have downloaded/installed bootstrap 4.0 (I have done it via Nuget package manager). You can add your customization on it -

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using Bootstrap version 4 which has included breaking changes to version 3, which is what the ASP.NET template is using. You can either rollback Bootstrap 4 to 3 using the Nuget package manager or [migrate](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/) it up to version 4.

Comment: I have rolled back Bootstrap 4 to 3 using Nuget package manager but i still receive warnings

Comment: This user had a similar problem and this fixed it for him. Your question has no details. What warnings? Have you completely emptied your browser cache and done a total refresh? <CTRL><F5>?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48488214/adding-new-theme-to-asp-net-mvc-5-dont-work/48488252#48488252